# the_post_thumbnail and multiple WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, loop

I have front-page.php with several loops - one for each category.

```
$queryX = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => X, 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) );

                    while ( $queryX->have_posts() ) {
                        ?>
                    <div class="news">
                            <?php
                            $queryX->the_post();
                            ?>
                            <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h6><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h6>' ); ?>
                            <figure>
                            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }

                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    ?>
```

Where X - is number (from 1 to 5, by number of categories). There are few news in every category with unique title, content and thumbnail. The problem with this loop is that first 3 loops work out alright, but 4th one displays 2 posts from 4th category with different titles and links, but the same thumbnail! Even more so, 5th loop also displays with 4th's thumbnail.

That's quite annoying and I don't get what am I missing, because:

- I've another theme with nearly the same code (it just adds
  ignore_sticky_posts), and it works out alright.
- First 3 work out
  fine.
- All posts are standard, all categories exists, posts are in
  right categories.
- I've tried, albeit for nothing, adding wp_query_reset() to the equation with nu success.

What am I missing?

Much appreciated any response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed last two loops had `$queryX->the_post();` after `the_post_thumbnail();` Now when I changed it - works perfectly! Hope it helps someone!